# How to updates/install mfc71u.dll, msvcp71.dll, msvcr71.dll in visual studio 2005

Tags: dll, windows-xp

I have an application which can require some of .dlls i.e  mfc71u.dll, msvcp71.dll,  msvcr71.dll while running.

Is there any Microsoft updates are there which can update visual studio 2005 so that I can install and my system can get that .dlls.

Thanks,
Kamal.

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 is version 8.0 meaning ATL8.0, mfc80.dll, etc, ATL7.1, mfc71u.dll belongs to visual studio 2003.

Comment: Thanks your quick reply . So i have to install vs 2003 or is there any service pack which can give this .dlls.

Answer (score 1):

The application has been created using Visual Studio 2003. You can install [Visual C++ .NET Runtime](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB932298/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=762).